# How to save real-time gps coordinates from geolocation watch into mysql table

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I'm fairly new to JS and PHP but I have been working on a large project which has many features for several months and its coming along nicely. The program is largely PHP and JS and will be used on computers in a fleet of vehicles.

One of the program features will use geofences and geolocation.watchPosition to monitor the user's GPS location and send a notification if the user leaves an assigned geofence.

What I need to accomplish is a way to continuously track the user's current location using geolocation.watchPosition and store any changes into the mysql table as they occur so that if the user leaves a defined geofenced area, they receive a notification that they have left the area.

I am able to obtain the users location, update the database with their login and logout locations, and calculate the difference in distance between the two locations. I have the geofences already configured.

How can use geolocation.watchPosition, JS and PHP to update a mysql table each time the user's gps location changes?

The following code sample is what I use to get the user's location and watch their location, but I have not found a way to update the mysql table each time the "info" variable, which contains their location, changes.

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>
  <body>
 <main class="container">
     <div id="map" class="map"></div>
      <!-- For displaying user's coordinate or error message. -->
     <div id="info" class="info"></div>
 </main>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&callback=init"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

const createMap = ({ lat, lng }) => {
  return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat, lng },
    zoom: 19
  });
};

const createMarker = ({ map, position }) => {
  return new google.maps.Marker({ map, position });
};

const getCurrentPosition = ({ onSuccess, onError = () => { } }) => {
  if ('geolocation' in navigator === false) {
    return onError(new Error('Geolocation is not supported by your browser.'));
  }

  return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
};

const getPositionErrorMessage = code => {
  switch (code) {
    case 1:
      return 'Permission denied.';
    case 2:
      return 'Position unavailable.';
    case 3:
      return 'Timeout reached.';
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

function init() {
  const initialPosition = { lat: 37.658440, lng: -120.993629 };
  const map = createMap(initialPosition);
  const marker = createMarker({ map, position: initialPosition });

  getCurrentPosition({
    onSuccess: ({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } }) => {
      marker.setPosition({ lat, lng });
      map.panTo({ lat, lng });
    },
    onError: err =>
      alert(`Error: ${getPositionErrorMessage(err.code) || err.message}`)
  });
}
// New function to track user's location.
const trackLocation = ({ onSuccess, onError = () => { } }) => {
  if ('geolocation' in navigator === false) {
    return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  });
};


  // Use watchPosition instead.
  return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError);
};

function init() {
  const initialPosition = { lat: 37.658440, lng: -120.993629 };
  const map = createMap(initialPosition);
  const marker = createMarker({ map, position: initialPosition });

  // Use the new trackLocation function.
  trackLocation({
    onSuccess: ({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } }) => {
      marker.setPosition({ lat, lng });
      map.panTo({ lat, lng });
    },
    onError: err =>
      alert(`Error: ${getPositionErrorMessage(err.code) || err.message}`)
  });
}
function init() {
  const initialPosition = { lat: 37.658440, lng: -120.993629 };
  const map = createMap(initialPosition);
  const marker = createMarker({ map, position: initialPosition });
  const $info = document.getElementById('info');

  trackLocation({
    onSuccess: ({ coords: { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } }) => {
      marker.setPosition({ lat, lng });
      map.panTo({ lat, lng });
      // Print out the user's location.
      $info.textContent = `Lat: ${lat} Lng: ${lng}`;
      // Don't forget to remove any error class name.
      $info.classList.remove('error');
    },
    onError: err => {
      // Print out the error message.
      $info.textContent = `Error: ${getPositionErrorMessage(err.code) || err.message}`;
      // Add error class name.
      $info.classList.add('error');
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you get a solution???

Comment: You solution is doomed to failure due to the refusal of W3C to accept the incredible demand for background geolocation functionality https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/745 even though a detailed solution was provided years ago https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen

Answer (score 0):

wacthposition returns an id on each new position.
May be you can try to make a function (callback, promise, interval...) looking for this change. After it occurs, you can insert data into your DB.